# Menubar on site not centering after many tries

Tags: html, css

I have a menubar on a site that's not centering. I've tried text-align:center everywhere, played around with margins and position, but I can't seem to get the text to be aligned with the main title regardless of screen size. Would you guys mind taking a look?

http://jsfiddle.net/9sqkL/

```
                <title>Test</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
                <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      </head>

      <body>
             <h1 style="text-align: center;">Test</h1>

      <div>
                <ul id="nav">
                <li ><a href="#" style="color:rgb(56,162,188);">HOME</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#" style="color:rgb(123,176,26);">PROJECTS</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#" style="color:rgb(243,45,93);">RESUME</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#" style="color:rgb(234,49,20);">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#" style="color:rgb(237,103,14);">ABOUT</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
      color: #26363d;
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
      font-weight: 300;
      line-height: 1.3em;
}
h1 {
      font-size: 60;
}
h2 {
      font-size: 25px;
}
h3 {
      font-size: 21px;
}
h4 {
      font-size: 19px;
}
h5 {
      font-size: 17px;
}
h6 {
      font-size: 15px;
}
body {
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
      background-image: url("background.png");
}

#nav {
    float: left;
width: 100% !important;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
    }
#nav li {

    float: left;
    }
#nav ul li {
     display: inline;
}
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
            }
#nav li a:hover {
    color: #c00;
    }
```

Comment: So please give a name to the menu in the CSS file, and put the condition there.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `float: left;` and `width: 100%` which is wrong so you need to remove 100% width, so that you can use `margin: auto;` and you don't need `float: left;` as you need your menu bar to be centered

Also you'll need a fixed width for `#nav` so that you can use `margin: auto;` for horizontal centering, as and when you add elements, just change the width of `#nav`.

As of now I've kept `550px` so you can change accordingly, the only CSS I've changed is in `#nav`

```
#nav {
    width: 550px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9sqkL/1/)

Comment: Thank you! Sorry about the trivial question!

Answer (score 0):

You've `float: left;` on your `ul` which is what's causing the issue. You can `display: inline-block;` the `li`'s and add `text-align: center;` on `ul` to center all the items inside the navigation. This way you won't even have to specify a fix width on the `ul`.

**[Working Demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/yiwp4j1q)**

If you specify a fixed width on the `ul` then it's just a matter of doing `margin: 0 auto;`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are two option naw **define your parent div width** than you can define **`magin:0 auto;`**

**as like this**

```
.mianNavcon{width:600px;margin:0 auto; // define your website }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="mianNavcon">
                <ul id="nav">
                <li ><a href="#" style="color:rgb(56,162,188);">HOME</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#" style="color:rgb(123,176,26);">PROJECTS</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#" style="color:rgb(243,45,93);">RESUME</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#" style="color:rgb(234,49,20);">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#" style="color:rgb(237,103,14);">ABOUT</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
```

**[Demo-1](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/9sqkL/4/)**

### ------------------

**Second Option is** this remove your `ID nav` float and `width` and now define

```
display inline-block;
```

as like this

```
.mianNavcon{text-align:center;}
#nav {
       display:inline-block;
    padding: 0;text-align:left;
    list-style: none;
        }
```

**[Demo-2](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/9sqkL/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Set an explicit absolute width of something like 481px (min) on `#nav` and remove `float:left`. [Demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/acuw2bkq)

Answer (score 0):

If you are making it responsive then u need to play with percentage for width and font-size, check the link below.

Also u need to use media queries.

I have given width to li, and when you float any element then u should even clear it.

```
#nav li {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 85%;
}

/*to clear floating LI*/
#nav ul:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/madhuri2987/9sqkL/5/

Hope this helps!